# How to forward optional arguments

Tags: clojure, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

Often it happens that I have a function that takes some optional arguments and passes them to other functions, which pass them further down the stack, and so on. How can this be done in Clojure without the types of error-prone complexity that I illustrate below?

1. If you pass the optional-argument variable directly, the callee can't accept it as optional arguments:

   ```
   (defn func1 [& {:keys [n-iterations] :or {n-iterations 20} :as opts}]
     (println "func1:" n-iterations)
     (func2 opts))

   (defn func2 [& {:keys [n-iterations]}]
     (println "func2:" n-iterations))

   user=> (func1 :n-iterations 15)
   func1: 15

   IllegalArgumentException No value supplied for key: {:n-iterations 15}  clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap.create (PersistentHashMap.java:77)
   ```
2. If the caller requires the optional arguments as a non-optional map argument, that's ugly and error-prone, and on top of that, it loses the defaults:

   ```
   (defn func2 [{:keys [n-iterations]}]  ;lost the &
     (println "func2:" n-iterations))

   user=> (func1 :n-iterations 15)
   func1: 15
   func2: 15
   nil
   user=> (func1)
   func1: 20
   func2: nil
   nil
   ```

   I've heard that you should take optional arguments at the top level and a non-optional map at all lower levels in the stack. I find that unsatisfactory, though, because often, especially at the REPL, I want to call any function at any "level", without regard to whether some other function calls it. It helps a lot to have a uniform calling convention.
3. If you forward an optional argument that's not supplied by the caller, Clojure turns it into a nil and then wraps it in an ArraySeq on each step down the stack:

   ```
   (defn func1 [& opts]
     (println "func1:" opts)
     (func2 opts))

   (defn func2 [& opts]
     (println (type opts))
     (println "func2:" opts)
     (func3 opts))

   (defn func3 [& opts]
     (println "func3:" opts))

   user=> (func1)
   func1: nil
   func2: (nil)
   func3: ((nil))
   ```

Most Clojure features have worked pretty smoothly for me, but this hasn't. What's the right way to do this?

The above is all under Clojure 1.9.0.

Answer (score 2):

> If you pass the optional-argument variable directly, the callee can't accept it as optional arguments

This isn't strictly true, it's just that when both functions take variadic arguments—in your case keyword args—and you destructure them into a single map, then you must `apply` them to other variadic functions in the same way you'd apply a map to them:

```
(defn func2 [& {:keys [n-iterations]}]
  (println "func2:" n-iterations))
(defn func1 [& {:keys [n-iterations]
                :or {n-iterations 20}
                :as opts}]
  (println "func1:" n-iterations)
  (apply func2 (mapcat identity opts)))
(func1 :n-iterations 15) ;; works fine
```

You couldn't call `func2` directly like `(func2 {:n-iterations 20})` either, which is effectively what's happening in your example.

> If the caller requires the optional arguments as a non-optional map argument, that's ugly and error-prone, and on top of that, it loses the defaults

You can still destructure with `:or` in this case.

```
(defn func2 [{:keys [n-iterations]
              :or {n-iterations 10}}]
  (println "func2:" n-iterations))
(func2 nil) ;; prints "func2: 10"
```

> If you forward an optional argument that's not supplied by the caller, Clojure turns it into a nil and then wraps it in an ArraySeq on each step down the stack

I think this is just a misunderstanding about how variadic arguments and destructuring work. In each of these functions, you're accepting variadic arguments and binding them to a single name `opts`. Inside your function body, `opts` is a collection. When you call other variadic functions with `opts` as the only argument, you're invoking them as *unary* functions. Look at it like this:

```
(foo [1 2 3])       ;; this is the call style you're getting
(foo 1 2 3)         ;; this is the call style you want
(apply foo [1 2 3]) ;; how to call `foo` with a coll variadic-ly
```

This is why it's necessary to `apply` your variadic, destructured-into-a-collection arguments to the other variadic functions.

There's another option:

```
(defn foo [x y z & [{:keys [a b c}]] ...)
```

This is variadic but takes an optional map in the first optional arg position.

You can also consider using multiple, fixed-arity definitions of your functions as suggested [here](https://stuartsierra.com/2015/06/01/clojure-donts-optional-arguments-with-varargs).